# Replace with uppercase characters with gsub

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

I have nubmers of simple strings `'som', 'man', 'pal'`, etc
How do i make vowel character `upcase!`, having vowel regex or array to have output like 'sOm', 'pAl', 'mAn' ?

Comment: fixed typo, vovel = vowel

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
"som".gsub(/[aeiou]/, &:upcase)
# => "sOm"
```

or

```
"som".tr("aeiou", "AEIOU")
# => "sOm"
```